# SwiftUI list multiselect with NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI running on macOS, for a list of items where each item in the list is a NavigationLink, multi-selection does not work. If the exact same view does *not* include the NavigationLink it works fine. **How can I have both multi-selection *and* NavigationLink in the same list running on macOS?** Perhaps this requires a different method of constructing NavigationLinks that isn't tied to the list? Is that even possible? I've tried conditionally disabling the NavigationLink when multiple rows are selected, but this has no effect (e.g. `.disabled(selection.count > 1)`).

Example where multi-select does not work (notice in the screenshot when three results are shift-clicked the full selection shows up briefly and then snaps to the last clicked item):

```swift
struct TestListView: View {
  @State var selection = Set<String>()
  let options = ["a", "b", "c"]

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(options, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
        NavigationLink {
          Text(String(describing: selection))
        } label: {
          Text(item)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Screencast of the above code]

Example where multi-select works fine:

```swift
struct TestListView: View {
  @State var selection = Set<String>()
  let options = ["a", "b", "c"]

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(options, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
        Text(item)
      }
      Text(String(describing: selection))
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I more or less had it in one of the question examples. A separate bug in a more complex example misled me. Solution is effectively the second option above.

In other words, *don't try to mix NavigationLink and multi-selection*. Instead skip the NavigationLink and put the destination view *next to* the List (only tested on macOS).

```swift
struct TestListView: View {
  @State var selection = Set<String>()
  let options = ["a", "b", "c"]

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(options, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
        Text(item)
      }
      if selection.isEmpty {
        Text("Empty")
      } else if selection.count > 1 {
        Text("Multiple")
      } else if let selection = selection.first {
        Text(selection)
      }
    }
  }
}
```