# SwiftUI List with editActions and NavigationLink gives compile time error

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

On iOS 16, I'm trying to set up editActions (move, delete, edit) in a SwiftUI `List` that's contained in a `NavigationStack`. It throws an error when `editActions` is used with a `NavigationLink` and a `@Published` property:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[TodoModel]' to expected argument type 'Binding<Data>'
```

Here's the code:

```
struct TodoModel: Identifiable, Hashable{
    
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: TodoViewModel
    @State var dummy  = ["a", "b", "c"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack{
            
            ///1. works with a State property
            List($dummy, id: \.self, editActions: .delete){ $todo in
                NavigationLink(value: todo, label: {Text(todo)})

            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self, destination: Dummy.init)
             
            
            ///2. works with ForEach[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            List{
                ForEach(viewModel.todos){ todo in
                    NavigationLink(value: todo, label: {Text(todo.name)})
                }
                .onDelete(perform: {index in
                    viewModel.todos.remove(atOffsets: index)

                })

            }.navigationDestination(for: TodoModel.self, destination: DetailView.init)
            
            ///this works
            //List(viewModel.todos, id: \.self ){ todo is
            
            //this throws a compiler error
            List(viewModel.todos, id: \.self, editActions: .all){ todo in
                NavigationLink(value: todo, label: {Text(todo.name)})

            }
            .navigationDestination(for: TodoModel.self, destination: DetailView.init)
            
        }
    }
}

class TodoViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var todos: [TodoModel] = [TodoModel(name: "A"), TodoModel(name: "B"), TodoModel(name: "A")]
    func addTodo(newElement: TodoModel){
        self.todos.append(newElement)
        
    }
}
```

Is it anything to do with the Published property? Because, in the above code it works when:

1. List populates from a State array
2. ForEach is used.

From what I've looked up, [SwiftUI List has issues when using multiselection and NavigationLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539222/swiftui-list-multiselect-with-navigationlink)

[image]

Comment: There is likely a typo somewhere else. Comment out sections until you find it.

Comment: Is todoList typeof @Published?

Comment: @JulianvanHeek yes. I've added the full source code (replaced "todoList" with "todos"